# undefined grapghics method using JRubyApplet instance

Tags: jruby

I get the following error using the JRubyApplet instance:

```
*Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1"
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NoMethodError) undefined method
'drawString' for  Java::SunJava2D::SunGraphics2D*
```

with the following script.rb :

```
include Java
JRUBY_APPLET.on_paint do |g|
  g.drawString("hello",0,0)
end
```

I have not succeed to puts any elements from AWT/Graphics

I guess my code is wrong but I don't know where.